# Force SSL and url encryption in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, https

In a rails app I am setting

```
config.force_ssl=true
```

This is working great, but I am concerned about a situation where a gem I am using redirects to a url in the following format:

```
http://example.com/secure_url?secret_token=abc
```

Rails then redirects to

```
https://example.com/secure_url?secret_token=abc
```

However, I'm worried that the secret_token will be exposed during the original http request before it is redirected to a secure connection. Is this a legitimate security concern?

Comment: if the token is a one-time-use, then exposing it is pretty irrelevant. it couldn't be re-used

Comment: In this case I'm pretty sure that is a one time use token so there isn't a concern, but I want to make sure that I understand correctly that if it wasn't one time use there would be a problem

Comment: theoretically, yes, if it's not a single-use token, then exposing it could be a problem.